# Organizing files in "buckets"

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I have a written a client side HTTP cache and I need to store the HTTP payload in the file system somehow. I do not want to clutter the filesystem with unnecessary files.

I have written this class:

```java
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2008, The Codehaus. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *   You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *   limitations under the License.
 *
 */

package org.codehaus.httpcache4j.cache;

import org.apache.commons.lang.Validate;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.AndFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.RegexFileFilter;

import org.codehaus.httpcache4j.util.DeletingFileFilter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class is internal and should never be used by clients. <p/>
 *
 * Responsible for creating and maintaining a "Pool" of file generations. <br/>
 * The files are promoted when they are accessed, so we can figure out which files that are OK to delete. <br/>
 * Known Gotchas: This needs to be in sync with the size of the storage engine. <br/>
 * If you have too few generations when you have many items in the cache, you might
 * be missing some files when you try to access them. <p/>
 *
 * Note from Despot: I am looking into another way of storing files, so this class might go away at some point,
 * or change to a different form. 
 *
 */
class FileGenerationManager implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1558644426181861334L;
    
    private final File baseDirectory;
    private final int generationSize;
    private final int numberOfGenerations;
    private final FileFilter generationFilter;

    public FileGenerationManager(final File baseDirectory, final int numberOfGenerations) {
        this(baseDirectory, numberOfGenerations, 100);
    }

    public FileGenerationManager(final File baseDirectory, final int numberOfGenerations, final int generationSize) {
        Validate.isTrue(numberOfGenerations > 0, "You may not create 0 generations");
        Validate.notNull(baseDirectory, "You may not have a null base directory");
        if (!baseDirectory.exists()) {
            Validate.isTrue(baseDirectory.mkdirs(), "Could not create base directory: " + baseDirectory);
        }
        this.baseDirectory = baseDirectory;
        this.generationSize = generationSize;
        this.numberOfGenerations = numberOfGenerations;
        generationFilter = new AndFileFilter(DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY, new RegexFileFilter("[0-9]*"));
        getGenerations();
    }

    /**
     * Creates generations of the directories in the base directory.
     *
     * @return the created generations.
     */
    //TODO: Is this heavy?
    //TODO: Maybe we should do this when we miss in getFile() ?
    public synchronized List<Generation> getGenerations() {
        final List<Generation> generations = new ArrayList<Generation>();
        //handle existing generations...
        File[] directories = baseDirectory.listFiles(generationFilter);
        if (directories.length > 0) {
            for (File directory : directories) {
                generations.add(new Generation(baseDirectory, Integer.parseInt(directory.getName())));
            }
        }
        else {
            generations.add(new Generation(baseDirectory, 1));
        }
        Collections.sort(generations);
        Generation currentGeneration = generations.get(0);
        if (currentGeneration.getGenerationDirectory().list().length > generationSize) {
            generations.add(0, new Generation(baseDirectory, currentGeneration.getSequence() + 1));
            removeLastGeneration(generations);
        }
        while (generations.size() > numberOfGenerations) {
            removeLastGeneration(generations);
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(generations);
    }

    private void removeLastGeneration(List<Generation> generations) {
        if (generations.size() > numberOfGenerations) {
            Generation generation = generations.remove(generations.size() - 1);
            generation.delete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the most recent created generation
     *
     * @return the generation with the highest sequence number
     */
    synchronized Generation getCurrentGeneration() {
        return getGenerations().get(0);
    }

    public synchronized File getFile(String fileName) {
        File target = new File(getCurrentGeneration().getGenerationDirectory(), fileName);
        for (Generation generation : getGenerations()) {
            File candidate = new File(generation.getGenerationDirectory(), fileName);
            if (candidate.exists()) {
                if (!target.equals(candidate)) {
                    //because of: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4017593
                    target.delete();
                    if (!candidate.renameTo(target)) {
                        return candidate;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
    
    static class Generation implements Comparable<Generation> {
        private File generationDirectory;
        private int sequence;

        public Generation(final File baseDir, final int generationNumber) {
            Validate.notNull(baseDir, "Generation directory may not be null");
            File genFile = new File(baseDir, String.valueOf(generationNumber));
            genFile.mkdirs();
            this.generationDirectory = genFile;
            this.sequence = generationNumber;
        }

        public synchronized void delete() {
            File[] undeleteableFiles = generationDirectory.listFiles(new DeletingFileFilter());
            if (undeleteableFiles == null || undeleteableFiles.length == 0) {
                generationDirectory.delete();
            }
            else {
                System.err.println("Unable to delete these files: " + Arrays.toString(undeleteableFiles));
            }
        }

        public File getGenerationDirectory() {
            return generationDirectory;
        }

        public int getSequence() {
            return sequence;
        }

        public int compareTo(Generation generation) {
            return 1 - (sequence - generation.sequence);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that sometimes the files are not moved to the correct folder, and I might leak file descriptors.

Do you have any suggestions for how to improve this?

Is there a standard solution for this maybe? regardless of language?

This is also pretty slow, speed enhancements are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean "sometimes the files are not moved to the correct folder"? is this a bug in your code or do you get an error? Also where is this slow? It's impossible to tell where the time is spent by looking at the code.

Comment: On windows, it seems like sometimes the target file is locked, as that is the only operating system that actually fails. If this is a bug in my code, I have not seen it.

The time is spent in the File.listFiles() method. As a number of objects are created in that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your performance problem (and probably bugs) are probably caused by using the file system excessively in marking generations, rather than storing this info in memory.  File system access is much more expensive than memory access -- in particular, **File.listFiles() or File.list() can be VERY slow.**  If you've got several thousand files, expect it to take **seconds** rather than milliseconds to execute on a Windows system using NTFS.

If possible, all of the generational info should be stored and updated as objects in a synchronized Collection.  If you just use the file system for actually storing, retrieving, and deleting the cached data files, you can stick all the cachefiles in one directory and call them whatever you want (just give the file a number or random name).

If the generational cache info needs to be persistent and safe against abrupt application shutdown, you can use serialized collections and periodically write this to disk (say, every 30 seconds, and again on application shutdown).  Since it is just a cache, you can do a check on app startup and delete cache entries with out a real file and delete files without a cache entry.

Alternately, you might look into using an embedded database the store the whole cache. H2 or HSQLDB are pure Java, very fast and lightweight, and support in-memory databases and embedded modes that are even faster.  This would let you store a lot more cache objects, and might be a lot faster, since the DBMS may cache frequently-used items in RAM.